# Bug in Programming Interviews Exposed: Linked Lists

Tags: c++, list, insert, linked-list

I was going through the Programming Interviews Exposed book. There's a code given for inserting an element at the front of linked lists.

```
bool insertInFront( IntElement **head, int data ){
    IntElement *newElem = new IntElement;
    if( !newElem ) return false;
    newElem->data = data;
    *head = newElem;
    return true;
}
```

IMHO this code forgets to update the next pointer of the new element, doesn't it ? Although I am sure the code is wrong, I just want to confirm my linked list concepts are not horribly wrong.

I believe the code should add the following line at the right place.

```
newElem->next = *head;
```

Can someone please just tell me whether I am right or wrong ?

Comment: You could [report](http://www.wiley.com/legacy/compbooks/programminginterview/errata.html) this as a bug.

Comment: Your answer is fine. There's no more problems with the code (besides its uglyness :))

Comment: Yuck, that's C++? :/ `new` never returns null, the first parameter should be a reference (never checks for null, pass null for `head` and boom; reference skips this mess), `IntElement` should have a constructor that takes the data (otherwise you're constructing and assigning, instead of just initializing), and yes, it forgets to link in the old head.

Comment: Sherlock might say maybe the interview question was "find the problems with this code"

Comment: So it appears shat book dates back to 2000 or so. In that case, they may have been working against a compiler that was not yet compliant with the '98 standard. (Back then VS6 was current but certainly had a lot of deviations from the standard.) That could explain the issue of the NULL test. But even so, it's still poor code in general.

Comment: Yes, it's a bug in the code, unfortunately. Will be fixed in the next edition. Note that the book says that examples are in C++ but without any use of C++'s OOP features, mostly so you can call new and delete. I will probably change this going forward.

Comment: Hey Eric! Your book did get me a job. Thanks. :) No hard feelings regarding the bug. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what kind of interview book you're reading, but this code example is terrible c++.

Yes, you need to point `newElem->next` to the old `head` before overwriting `head`.  Also, there's no reason to check if newElem is NULL - if it couldn't be allocated, C++ throws an exception.  Also, `insertInFront` should be a member function of `IntElement`, and `head` should be a data member.

Answer (score 5):

Since this is inserting in the front, you're right. The new nodes's next should be the current head, then head should be set to point to the new node.

```
bool insertInFront( IntElement **head, int data ){
    IntElement *newElem = new IntElement;
    if( !newElem ) return false;
    newElem->data = data;
    newElem->next = *head;
    *head = newElem;
    return true;
}
```

Of course, there are several other things here that are bad style and design, or just plain wrong.